# Cannot assign "'HR'": "Employee.department" must be a "Department" instance

Tags: python, django

when I try to feel department field is show me this error.
I don't understand this error.. please help me out

```
Cannot assign "'HR'": "Employee.department" must be a "Department" instance.
```

here is my model.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 20,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length= 20, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length= 20, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length  = 50, null=True)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length = 30,null=True)
    contact_num = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.employee_name
```

here is my form.py

```
class AdForm(forms.ModelForm):
    employee_name = forms.CharField()
    surname = forms.CharField ()
    address = forms.CharField ()
    qualification = forms.CharField ()
    contact_num = forms.IntegerField ()
    department = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
       model = Employee
       fields = ('employee_name',
                 'surname',
                 'address',
                 'qualification',
                 'contact_num',
                 'department')
```

here is my view.py

```
def create(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = AdForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid(): #getting error on this
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('employee-list'))
   else:
       form = AdForm()
   return render(request, 'employee/create.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Can you add new sentence to question - there are always 168 values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `department` field on your `Employee` model is a `ForeignKey` field, but in your `AdForm` you define it as `CharField`.

You could fix the field definition in your form. Alternatively, you could also simply remove the explicit field definition. When using a model form, Django will select the correct field type for you.

```
class AdForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Employee
       fields = ('employee_name',
                 'surname',
                 'address',
                 'qualification',
                 'contact_num',
                 'department')
```

This will render the department field as a `<select>` widget, allowing you to select from your (pre-existing) departments.

Comment: @Jolly glad I could help! Don‘t forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark so others can see that your problem has been solved - and so I can reap some extra reputation points ;) And welcome to StackOverflow!